# manual execution of specific remote query with postgresql_fdw

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data, postgresql-fdw

In 9.4b2, `postgresql_fdw` doesn't know how to "push down" aggregate queries on remote tables, e.g.

```
> explain verbose select max(col1) from remote_tables.table1;
                                         QUERY PLAN                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=605587.30..605587.31 rows=1 width=4)
   Output: max(col1)
   ->  Foreign Scan on remote_tables.table1  (cost=100.00..565653.20 rows=15973640 width=4)
         Output: col1, col2, col3
         Remote SQL: SELECT col1 FROM public.table1
```

It would obviously be much more efficient to send `SELECT max(col1) FROM public.table1` to the remote server and just pull the one row back.

Is there a way to perform this optimization manually? I would be satisfied with something as low-level as (hypothetically speaking)

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT max(col1) FROM public.table1' ON remote RETURNING (col1 INTEGER);
```

although of course a higher-level construct would be preferred.

I'm aware that I could do something like this with `dblink`, but that would involve rewriting a large body of code that already uses foreign tables, so I'd prefer not to.

EDIT: Here's the query plan for Erwin Brandstetter's suggestion:

```
=> explain verbose select col1 from remote_tables.table1 
-> order by col1 desc nulls last limit 1;
                                            QUERY PLAN                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=645521.40..645521.40 rows=1 width=4)
   Output: url
   ->  Sort  (cost=645521.40..685455.50 rows=15973640 width=4)
         Output: col1
         Sort Key: table1.col1
         ->  Foreign Scan on remote_tables.table1  (cost=100.00..565653.20 rows=15973640 width=4)
               Output: col1
               Remote SQL: SELECT col1 FROM public.table1
```

This is *better*, in that it fetches only `col1`, but it's still dragging 16 million rows over the network and now it's also sorting them.  By way of comparison, the original query, applied on the remote server, doesn't even have to scan, because that column has an index.  (The core query planner isn't clever enough to do that for the modified query applied on the remote server, but that's minor.)

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, it seems that the best available option is to create a view on the remote server that encapsulates the query needing to be "pushed down".  `postgres_fdw` is happy to define and use foreign tables backed by views on the remote, and regular old query optimization *within* the view does the Right Thing.  For instance, given

```
CREATE VIEW id_ranges AS
SELECT 'url_strings'::text AS tbl,
    min(url_strings.id)::bigint AS lo,
    max(url_strings.id)::bigint AS hi
   FROM url_strings
UNION
 SELECT 'captured_pages'::text AS tbl,
    min(captured_pages.url)::bigint AS lo,
    max(captured_pages.url)::bigint AS hi
   FROM captured_pages
UNION
 -- ... several more like that ...
```

on the remote, and a `FOREIGN TABLE` of the same name on the local server,

```
SELECT lo, hi FROM id_ranges WHERE tbl = 'url_strings';
```

the existing pushdown optimization will send the WHERE constraint to the remote, and the remote will scan only one table (making use of indexes if possible) and send back a single-row result.

Answer (score 0):

[Remote Query Optimization](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/postgres-fdw.html#AEN158635) is rather basic:

> `postgres_fdw` attempts to optimize remote queries to reduce the amount
>   of data transferred from foreign servers. This is done by sending
>   query `WHERE` clauses to the remote server for execution, and by not
>   retrieving table columns that are not needed for the current query. [...]

My first idea to substitute with the following isn't much of an improvement either as you found out:

```
SELECT col1
FROM   public.table1
ORDER  BY col1 DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1;
```

Currently (including pg 9.4), only `WHERE` conditions with all immutable functions are pushed down. I found this exhaustive thread discussing the [Status of FDW pushdowns](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CADyhKSXGGtETULADsmWE86UA9mC_z95XbB_CmjuwN2zPWaSzqg@mail.gmail.com#CADyhKSXGGtETULADsmWE86UA9mC_z95XbB_CmjuwN2zPWaSzqg@mail.gmail.com) on pgsql-hackers.

Your best option seems to use dblink like you already mentioned yourself.

Comment: Alas, the sort happens locally.

Comment: @Zack: Too bad. Currently, really only `WHERE` conditions with all immutable functions are pushed down.